# Using Eigen/Sparse library in c++, is there a way to delete columns from a sparse matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, sparse-matrix

I have built a matrix which is n rows by n+4 columns, there are four specific columns which I would need to delete to make this into a square. Is there a way to do this with eigen?  I have had a look at their Docs and I can't seem to find anything.

Thanks all,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication, e.g.

```
SparseMatrix<double> X(10,14);
for (int i = 0; i<14; i++) X.coeffRef(0, i) += (double) (i+1);

SparseMatrix<double> Y(14, 10); 
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)  Y.coeffRef(i, i) += 1.0;    

cout << X*Y << endl << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... now, there is! :-)

It makes a lot of sense, because it can be implemented with almost no cost, while other solutions are a little expensive.

Here is the commit:
https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/commit/67a1e881d932928c4dc24ea02f5298105e2c4958#9b73cdaaf42b0a6d50abe5fb3dc5ab6e3be5502f_476_475

The method is called `removeOuterVectors()`.

Here is the relevant issue:
https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2659